# Powershell: LegacyExchangeDN value getting truncated when pulling from O365

Tags: powershell, csv

Via PowerShell, I log onto O365 and run the following which pulls data and outputs it to a CSV file:

```
function O365Logon
{
#Check for current open O365 sessions and allow the admin to either use the existing session or create a new one
$session = Get-PSSession | ?{$_.ConfigurationName -eq 'Microsoft.Exchange'}
if($session -ne $null)
{
    $a = Read-Host "An open session to Office 365 already exists.  Do you want to use this session?  Enter y to use the open session, anything else to close and open a fresh session."
    if($a.ToLower() -eq 'y')
    {
        Write-Host "Using existing Office 365 Powershell Session." -ForeGroundColor Green
        return  
    }
    $session | Remove-PSSession
}
Write-Host "Please enter your Office 365 credentials" -ForeGroundColor Green
$cred = Get-Credential
$s = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
$importresults = Import-PSSession -Prefix "Cloud" $s
}

function Main
{

#Import user list from migration.csv file. Specifies account names to retrieve data for
$MigrationCSV = Import-Csv $migrationCSVFileName

#Get mailbox list based on email addresses from CSV file
$MailBoxList = $MigrationCSV | %{$_.EmailAddress} | Get-CloudMailbox
$Users = @()

#Get LegacyDN, Tenant, On-Premise Email addresse, and MailBox GUID for each of the users
$Outfile = ".\cloud.csv"
'LegacyExchangeDN,CloudEmailAddress,OnPremiseEmailAddress,MailboxGUID' | Set-Content $Outfile


foreach($user in $MailBoxList)
{
$CloudEmailAddress = $user.EmailAddresses | ?{($_ -match 'onmicrosoft') -and ($_ -cmatch 'smtp:')}

    if ($CloudEmailAddress.Count -gt 1)
    {
        $CloudEmailAddress = $CloudEmailAddress[0].ToString().ToLower().Replace('smtp:', '')
        Write-Host "$user returned more than one cloud email address.  Using $CloudEmailAddress" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    else
    {
        $CloudEmailAddress = $CloudEmailAddress.ToString().ToLower().Replace('smtp:', '')
    }

  $Data = @(
             $user.LegacyExchangeDN,
             $CloudEmailAddress,
             $user.PrimarySMTPAddress.ToString(),
             $user.ExchangeGUID 
            )
 '"{0}",{1},{2},{3}' -f $Data | Add-Content $Outfile
}


Write-Host "File Successfully Exported to cloud.csv" -ForeGroundColor Green

}
```

The problem is the first ($user.LegacyExchangeDN) value is always truncated at 128 characters in both the console output as well as in the CSV file.

Sample returned data:

"/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=a0dd27b566c841108cfa61a3494206c6-**Jonathan, M**",mJonathan@ThisSampleDomainGroup.onmicrosoft.com,mJonathan@ThisSampleDomain.com,49C38C07-6997-4D4D-9449-EBD5A53E3D02

"/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=ba1189838c964929bff706a23900d41c-**Smith, Chri**",cSmith@ThisSampleDomainGroup.onmicrosoft.com,cSmith@ThisSampleDomain.com,9F0E3433-6749-47B7-96E5-987CF5ACF60D

You'll see the first name for each user is truncated, but differently.

I first thought the names are truncated in O365 but was told that's not true.  Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot or resolve?

Answer (score 0):

http://help.outlook.com/140/dd575549.aspx#Mailboxes doesn't seem to reference Get-CloudMailbox.  Are you using the Connect-MsolService or a PowerShell connection to https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/?

Have you tried using Get-Mailbox?

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity mJonathan@ThisSampleDomain.com | Select LegacyExchangeDN | FL
```

**EDIT:**

```
Get-CloudMailbox -Identity mJonathan@ThisSampleDomain.com | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LegacyExchangeDN
```

**EDIT #2:**

```
(Get-CloudMailbox -Identity mJonathan@ThisSampleDomain.com | Select LegacyExchangeDN -ExpandProperty LegacyExchangeDN).Length
```

Comment: I'm using the Get-PSSession to connect to Microsoft.Exchange

Comment: I've added the O365 function I use to connect.

Comment: I tried using the get-Mailbox command but it wasn't recognized. It imported the other commands fine but it doesn't know that one(?)

Comment: get-Mailbox worked through the console but not through PowerGui.  Disregard the problem running the get-mailbox command.

Comment: Okay, I got the results of the "Get-Mailbox" command and it's the same truncated string.

Comment: See my edit and tell me if -ExpandProperty shows the entire value.

Comment: Nope, I thought this was going to be it.  I had to put the -ExpandProperty before the fieldname in the select statement to get it to work but nada.  It still truncates it at 128 characters.  /o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=a0dd27b566c841108cfa61a3494206c6-Jonathan, M

Comment: It's not an Office 365 issue.  Seems that the LegacyExchangeDN has a limit of 128 characters.  See my edit for a command I am running in our environment (40,000 users+) which is returning 0 users.  I can't find the documentation on the LegacyExchangeDN size, but from what I've just seen that's the limit.

Comment: Actually it just started returning some users, one with 136 characters.  I'm running the Get-CloudMailbox from above.  Do you have a local Exchange 2010 server installed by any chance?

Comment: I can't get the get-CloudMailbox command to work from a powershell command window (PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-cloudmailbox) but I can get it to work via PowerGUI($MailBoxList = $MigrationCSV | %{$_.EmailAddress} | Get-CloudMailbox )

Comment: Yes, we do have an Exchange 2010 server on premise.

Comment: The Get-CloudMailbox only works when you make sure to include the -Prefix "Cloud" in your Import-PSSession command, which you do above in your script (missed that the first time).  That adds before the noun in all of the session commands.  If you are running the same connection settings within the console it should work just the same.  If it doesn't you can try removing Cloud and just do Get-Mailbox, but if done on an Exchange server it may cause issues, it may not.

Comment: Can you try my latest edit to confirm the ExchangeLegacyDN for that user is longer than 128?

Comment: Unfortunately, the users I'm working with are on O365 not on-premise.  I'll check to see if we have any local user accounts who would exceed the 128 theoretical character limit.

Comment: That's fine, disregard my on-premise question.  My edit #2 should run in your O365 environment.

Comment: Given that this is an o365 environment, the LegacyNetworkDN on-premise looks different from the one pulled from o365.  There's no GUID after 'cn=' in the on-premise one.  However, in the o365, it adds a GUID in the 'cn='. Could it just be a 128 character restriction in o365?

Comment: No, I am able to return LegacyExchangeDN values greater than 128 in my O365 environment.

Comment: Is there a way for me to see what's in the O365 field outside of PowerShell?  I'd like to see if there is only 128 characters of data out there.  Maybe it's pulling the entire string but they don't have the fields populated correctly(?)